# How to pass multiple values using multiple selectors

Tags: php, jquery, submit, css-selectors

Here is what I have done so far:

```
<label for="popupDatepicker">DOB<span class="red">*</span></label>
<input  class="text1" type=text id="popupDatepicker" name="popupDatepicker" maximun=30>
<label for="gender">I am<span class="red">*</span></label>
<select name="gender" id="gender">
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#gender").blur(function() { // when focus out

        //$("#message").html(''); //before AJAX response

        var form_data = {
            action: 'gender',
            gender: $(this).val(),
            popupDatepicker: $(this).val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions.php",
            data:form_data,

            success: function(result) {
                $("#genders").html(result);
                //alert("Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");  
            }
        });

    });

});
```

I want to pass both birthdate *and* gender after selecting the gender.

Comment: On form submit call serialize(),

Comment: Are you sure thats your html? where is the gender input?

Comment: thank you ...actually i don`t want on form submit ....is der any way

Comment: add same class for both input fields ,then refer that class name ,then trigger on "Onchange" event

Comment: @zaf its dropdown list Male and female

Comment: @Yuvraj_Ingale Would be a good idea for you to paste that part as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing this, is simply adding the individual post variables within the data blob directly within the ajax call.

For example (not tested - may break):

```
data: ({
    a:'gender',
    g:$('#gender').val(),
    d:$('#popupDatepicker').val()
}),
```

On the server side you'll see the 'a', 'g' and 'd' post variables!

Comment: I think you want `#gender` in the first selector :-)